# What installer is used by ubuntu 18.04 LTs and Ubuntu20.04 LTS server image?

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, ubiquity, debian-installer

This is really confusing compared to "Anaconda" installer we have been using with CentOS.
What is the installer used on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server and Ubuntu 20 LTs Server images?

When I go through documentation, it says using debian-installer but then same document also mentions that use "ubuntu-installer" for automated installation (pressed). There is also announcement on same page that Ubuntu 20 LTS have moved to Ubuntu installer and getting rid of "debian installer".

Also, other confusions are about ubiquity, subiquity and curtin - are they also present in Ubuntu Server images?

Please clarify? I am only interested in the "SERVER" images, as I understand "ubuntu installer" in the one with GUI support so that's valid for Desktop images?

Thanks,
Udit

Comment: Not too sure what you're asking about.  CentOS doesn't use the `anaconda` installer.  (I don't know what it uses, though.)  Anaconda is a program that manages environments of independent programs.  CentOS is an operating system, like Ubuntu and Debian.  Anaconda is "one level down" from the OS level.  After you install Ubuntu or Debian, you can install Anaconda within them, if you want.

Comment: That's not true. CentOS 8 does use Anaconda as an installer, on boot time, there is Anaconda systemd service. What you are talking about it just Anaconda program. Here is link to Anaconda Installer on Fedora, samei available on Ubuntu

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda

Comment: Oh, ok!  Fair enough.  Ubuntu (as far as I know) doesn't use Anaconda and I'm not sure why you need to know.  That is, what is it you're trying to do and how is knowing going to help you with what you're planning to do.  The difference between server and desktop is just the selection of packages.  So, if you want the "server" version but use a GUI, then you can just install the desktop image but remove all the desktop software.  It's tedious, but not impossible.